# Fixing a broken workbook file path using vba

Tags: excel

I have been building a project planning book and within this you fill out a section with data relevant to the work coming up. The data is then linked to another workbook to auto-populate. Simple. The issue is, these two workbooks are automatically copied and pasted into another folder in another file structure, with a different name in reference to the client that the project is for.

With the name and file path changed, the file link is then broken and you have to reset it every time to the new named file. Both workbooks end up in the same folder and the name of the new workbooks appear within each book. Is there a way to have a button auto-relink with the new name?

I am fairly new to the Excel VBA game and have just been learning what I need as I have been building this project book.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Provide a box to specify the file path. Otherwise do you expect some vba code to search the harddrive for the other file?

Comment: If the workbooks are automatically being copied and renamed, then the location and file name must be available during this process, why not use this information to update the the links?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have two Excel workbooks, one is located at `C:\DIR\SubDir1\File1.xls` and the other in `C:\DIR\SubDir2\File2.xls`.
If you add inside `File1.xls` a reference to `C:\DIR\SubDir2\File2.xls` and you move `C:\DIR` to `C:\Other_DIR`, then, obviously, it won't work.

If, however, inside `File1.xls`, you add a reference to `..\SubDir2\File2.xls` and you perform the same move, there is no reason for the whole thing not to work.

In other words, are you working with absolute or relative file references?

Comment: Thank you! That would work. How would I referencing the file path from a cell within Workbook 1? So the current work process is: The project is given a number and a client name (123456 - Company Name ). When a new project is started, the original blank workbooks are copied into another location and the workbook names go from being "# - 'Client' Project Book" to being "123456 - Company Name Project Book. Both the reference number and company name variables are in the project book. Can I create a path within a cell with the two variables and have the link reference that cell as the file path?